# Why is this piecewise function continuous at $a = 0$, but this other similar piecewise function isn't.

Tags: continuity

Take

$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
    1,\quad x∈ℚ \\ 
    0,\quad x∉ℚ
\end{cases}$$

and

$$g(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
    x,\quad x∈ℚ \\ 
    0,\quad x∉ℚ
\end{cases}$$

where $f(x)$ is not continuous at $a=0$, in fact it's not continuous anywhere, and $g(x)$ is continuous at $a=0$ but not elsewhere.

Now I understand the proof behind $f(x)$ not being continuous anywhere but I don't understand why $g(x)$ is continuous at $a=0$.

I used the logic that $ℚ$ is dense to prove $f(x)$ is not continuous anywhere but given $g(x)$ looks similar, I don't understand how it can be different. I'd appreciate any pointers or tips.

Comment: The continuity of $g$ in $0$ can be directly checked with the usual $\epsilon$-$\delta$-definition. And I'm pretty convinced this question is a duplicate ...

Comment: @localshop Actually yes I understand now, looking at the graph $f(x)$ ping pongs between 0 to 1 at $a=0$ and since the rationals and irrationals are dense, it doesn't settle down to 1 value. $g(x)$ does

Comment: there is a jump discontinuity at each rational, and the size of the jump is of size of the rational. So the jump at the rational $x=0$ is a jump of size zero, which is no jump at all.

Answer (score 2):

They are not that similar. In fact, we have $|g(x)|\leq |x|$ for each $x$, so when $|x|$ is small, $g(x)$ is very close to $g(0)=0$. Using this inequality, continuity at $0$ is easy to prove with the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition.

Comment: You're right I see it now. Is there a way I can close this question?

Comment: @BillCogn Why would you want to close it? Other users might learn from these questions in the future.